# Keep ratio of button when use image background in Android?

Tags: android

I am using the image background and set the width match parent, but the height of the button equals the height of image. How to set the ratio of button to be equal to the ratio of image?

See this image:

[image: See this picture]

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:gravity="center">

<Button
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
    android:background="@drawable/button"
    android:onClick="start"
    android:text="@string/main_startLabel"
    android:textAllCaps="false" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:textAllCaps="false"
    android:text="@string/main_aboutLabel"
    android:onClick="about"/>
```

Update: Just add line  **android:adjustViewBounds="true"**

Answer (score 0):

Please remove

```
android:height="50dip"
```

And you should use nine-patch drawable: https://developer.android.com/studio/write/draw9patch.html